# Why does trying to use string? (Nullable string) in C# produce a syntax error?

Tags: c#, .net, string, nullable

I have a method that returns `null` if the postcode is invalid, and just returns the `string` if it is valid. It also transforms the data in certain cases.

I have the following unit test below but I am getting syntax errors on the lines where it is using `string?`. Could anyone tell me why?

```
    public void IsValidUkPostcodeTest_ValidPostcode()
    {
        MockSyntaxValidator target = new MockSyntaxValidator("", 0);
        string fieldValue = "BB1 1BB";
        string fieldName = "";
        int lineNumber = 0;
        string? expected = "BB1 1BB"; 
        string? actual;

        actual = target.IsValidUkPostcode(fieldValue, fieldName, lineNumber);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

Comment: Oh dear. Bad day at the office, completely forget strings don't have to be nullable. #facepalm

Comment: No, don't delete.  Let us all bask in your derpitude.

Comment: Glad you got that sorted out :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `?` suffix on the name of a type is an alias for using [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) (section 4.1.10 of the C# 4 spec). The type parameter for `Nullable<T>` has the [`struct` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
```

This constrains `T` to be a non-nullable value type. That prohibits you from using `string`, as `System.String` is a reference type.

Fortunately, *as* string is a reference type, you don't need to use `Nullable<T>` - it already has a null value (the null reference):

```
string x = null; // No problems here
```

Comment: this is a much better explanation Jon

Comment: In C# 8.0 reference types may be marked as nullable. One may type `string?` to tell the world this string may be null. Ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdC0aoa7ung

Answer (score 6):

`string` is already a nullable type an doesn't need a `?`